# Conversion between sub-classes using Curiously Recursive Template Pattern

Tags: c++, templates, template-meta-programming, crtp

### Given:

- a template class `Base` with the typename argument `value_type`,
- its [Curiously Recursive Template
  Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern) template "sub-classes" `DerivedFoo` and `DerivedBar`, and
- template "sub-class" `DerivedBarCode` and `DerivedBarDoge` which are derived from `DerivedBar`,

### How may I, or is it possible for me to:

- achieve conversion (via explicit constructor, assignment operator, *etc.*) between every pair of the three leaf derived types as indicated in the diagram, and
- disable (via a compiler error message) conversions that aren't specified in the diagram?

**The diagram:**

```
Base -+---> DerivedFoo <-------+
      +-+-> DerivedBar         | // Three-way
        +---> DerivedBarCode <-+ // conversion
        +---> DerivedBarDoge <-+
```

### The scenario is abstracted from:

```
MatrixBase -+---> DenseMatrix <------------+
            +-+-> SparseMatrixBase         | 
              +---> MatrixCSR <------------+ // Multiple-way
              +---> MatrixCSC <------------+ // conversion
              +---> MatrixModifiedCSR <----+
              +---> MatrixModifiedCSC <----+
```

where every class has at least one common template argument, `typename value_type`.

### Minimum demonstrative example:

**Explanation:**

- **Lines 116...128** and **lines 160...169** shows my attempt at defining the explicit template constructor of a template class outside the template class, to convert `DerivedBarCode<value_type>` and `DerivedBarDoge<value_type>` into `DerivedFoo<value_type>`.
- **Line 49** contains the static assertion which stalls for all conversions not specified in the diagram.
- Remove **lines 189...202** along with **lines 116...128** and **lines 160...169** to successfully compile and run.

**Code:**

```
#include <iostream>

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Base
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
template <typename value_type, typename derived_type>
class Base
{
public:
    // Pass along the value type.
    typedef value_type value_type;
    // Identify myself in the Curiously Recursive Template Pattern hierarchy.
    typedef Base object_type;
    // Delegate to derived types.
    derived_type & asLeaf() { return static_cast<derived_type &>(*this); }

protected:
    value_type m_Base;

public:
    Base(value_type base = value_type()) : m_Base(base) {}

public:
    // A delegated function
    void Dump() { asLeaf().Dump(); }
};

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Base -----> Derived Foo
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
template <typename value_type>
class DerivedFoo : public Base < value_type, DerivedFoo<value_type> >
{
public:
    // Identify myself in the CRTP hierarchy.
    typedef DerivedFoo object_type;

protected:
    value_type m_Foo;

public:
    DerivedFoo(value_type base = value_type(), value_type foo = value_type()) :
        Base < value_type, DerivedFoo<value_type> >(base), m_Foo(foo) {}

    template <typename object_type_2>
    DerivedFoo(object_type_2 const &other)
    {
        static_assert(false, "Non-specialized template constructor disabled.");
    }

public:
    // A possible implementation of the delegated function
    void Dump()
    {
        std::cout << "DerivedFoo = [" << m_Base << ", " << m_Foo << "]\n";
    }
};

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Base -+---> DerivedFoo -+ Two-way
//       +---> DerivedBar -+ conversion
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
template <typename value_type, typename bar_type>
class DerivedBar : public Base < value_type, DerivedBar<value_type, bar_type> >
{
public:
    // Pass along the derived bar type.
    typedef bar_type bar_type;
    // Identify myself in the CRTP hierarchy.
    typedef DerivedBar object_type;
    // Delegate to derived types.
    bar_type & asLeaf() { return static_cast<bar_type &>(*this); }

protected:
    value_type m_Bar;

public:
    DerivedBar(value_type base = value_type(), value_type bar = value_type()) :
        Base < value_type, DerivedBar<value_type, bar_type> >(base), m_Bar(bar)
    {}

public:
    void Dump() { asLeaf().Dump(); }
};

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Base -+---> DerivedFoo <-------+
//       +-+-> DerivedBar <-------+ Three-way conversion
//         +---> DerivedBarCode <-+
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
template <typename value_type>
class DerivedBarCode :
    public DerivedBar < value_type, DerivedBarCode<value_type> >
{
public:
    typedef DerivedBarCode object_type;

protected:
    value_type m_Code = 8;

public:
    DerivedBarCode(value_type base = value_type(),
        value_type bar = value_type(), value_type code = value_type()) :
        DerivedBar < value_type, DerivedBarCode<value_type> >(base, bar),
        m_Code(code) {}

public:
    void Dump()
    {
        std::cout << "DerivedBarCode = ["
            << m_Base << ", " << m_Bar << ", " << m_Code << "]\n";
    }
};

// DerivedBarCode => DerivedFoo
// Example of what I'm trying to do:
template <typename value_type>
template <>
DerivedFoo<value_type>::DerivedFoo(
    typename DerivedBarCode<value_type>::object_type const &other)
{
    m_Base = other.m_Base;
    m_Foo = other.m_Foo;
    // There may be other calculations, e.g. replacing the line above with:
    // m_Foo = other.m_Foo + other.m_Code;
    std::cout << "m_Code = " << other.m_Code << '\n';
}

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Base -+---> DerivedFoo <-------+
//       +-+-> DerivedBar <-------+ Four-way
//         +---> DerivedBarCode <-+ conversion
//         +---> DerivedBarDoge <-+
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
template <typename value_type>
class DerivedBarDoge :
    public DerivedBar < DerivedBarDoge<value_type>, value_type > 
{
public:
    typedef DerivedBarDoge object_type;

protected:
    value_type m_Doge;

public:
    DerivedBarDoge(value_type base = value_type(),
        value_type bar = value_type(), value_type dance = value_type()) :
        DerivedBar < DerivedBarDoge<value_type>, value_type >(base, bar),
        m_Code(dance) {}

    void Dump()
    {
        std::cout << "DerivedBarDoge = ["
            << m_Base << ", " << m_Bar << ", " << m_Doge << "]\n";
    }

};

// DerivedBarDoge => DerivedFoo
// Another attempt.
template <typename value_type>
template <>
DerivedFoo<value_type>::DerivedFoo(DerivedBarDoge<value_type> const &other)
{
    m_Base = other.m_Base;
    m_Foo = other.m_Foo;
    std::cout << "m_Doge = " << other.m_Doge << '\n';
}


int main()
{
    DerivedFoo<double> foo(1.0, 2.0);
    foo.Dump();
    // Output:
    // DerivedFoo = [1, 2];

    DerivedBarCode<double> barcode(4.0, 8.0, 16.0);
    barcode.Dump();
    // Output:
    // DerivedBarCode = [4, 8, 16];

    DerivedBarDoge<double> bardoge(32.0, 64.0, 128.0);
    bardoge.Dump();
    // Output:
    // DerivedBarDoge = [32, 64, 128];

    DerivedFoo<double> converted(barcode);
    converted.Dump();
    // Expected output:
    // DerivedFoo = [4, 8];

    converted = bardoge;
    converted.Dump();
    // Expected output:
    // DerivedFoo = [32, 64];

    barcode = foo;
    barcode.Dump();
    // Expected output:
    // DerivedFoo = [1, 2, 16];

    // system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you provide explicit conversion operators, yes

Comment: There are *only* leaf derived types. There is no such thing as `Base`, only `Base<SomeDerived>`s which are statically known to be `SomeDerived`s. Other type pairs are unrelated and you need to explicitly write conversion code for them. It is not recommended to have implicit conversions. Write functions named like `convert_DerivedBarCode_to_DerivedBarDoge`.

Comment: @n.m. Your approach looks promising; where should I define these functions? Would you recommend member functions like `DerivedBarCode::ConvertToDerivedBarDoge()` as well?

Comment: `DerivedBarCode::ConvertToDerivedBarDoge()` style is OK. As long as it is consistently adhered to, no need to provide additional variants in the global namespace or `ConvertFrom...`.

Comment: There are 20 different conversions implied by your real problem (5 choose 2, two ways).  Are their implementations common?  Probably `SparseX<-->Dense` will be defined with `SparseX` -- but who owns `SparseX<-->SparseY`?  What happens when you add a new type `SparseZ`?

Comment: @Yakk `SparseBase` -> `DenseMatrix` will be common while not the reverse. So, you imply that there will be more conversions... The sparse matrices currently share 3 vectors defined in `SparseBase`.

Comment: @frenzydt. Ok, that is 4/20 that are common.  4/20 that are custom for a tyoe.  What about the other 12? (directly between sparse matrixes), are they an illusion of your diagram?

Comment: @yakk Yes. I would like to have all conversion made. I can think of a method: Implement `SparseX <-> DenseMatrix`; to convert `SparseX -> SparseY`, perform the default `SparseX -> DenseMatrix -> SparseY` if another conversion isn't specified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CRTP bases will inject their class names into the derived class. So if each CRTP base knows the derived type to be `derived_type`, then getting to the other base `other_base< derived_type >` is a simple matter of

```
static_cast< typename derived_type::other_base & >(
            static_cast< derived_type & >( * this ) );
```

If the CRTP base mixin may be implemented by any of several templates, then it should add a typedef to its own type, to identify which mixin it is. Then use that for `::other_base`.

To add conversions, just put such a cast into a conversion operator template. Be sure to sanitize the conversion with SFINAE before actually attempting it.

```
template< typename t,
    std::enable_if_t< std::is_base_of_v< t, derived_type > > * = nullptr >
operator t & ()
    { return etc; }
```

You could additionally/alternately tag all suitable mixins with a member typedef, and SFINAE check for that tag instead. To select only the transitions in the diagram, upgrade the tag to a Boolean metafunction.

Comment: @FrenzYDT. A base class which provides added functionality — the general use case of CRTP.

Comment: What's the purpose of your first code block? For an inheritance tree like "A derives B, B derives C", is `B` the `other_base`?

Comment: Most of the sub-class conversions will be manual; although conversion of sparse matrices to the DenseMatrix could follow a single template function which iterates through all non-zero entries of the sparse matrix, converting DenseMatrix to each of the SparseMatrix's requires different algorithms. Conversions between each of the SparseMatrix's are likely to be different either.

Answer (score 1):

First, stop thinking about your template hierarchy.  Second, stop thinking about casting.

Which seemingly doesn't leave much, but it leaves enough.

Suppose we have 3 unrelated types: Alice, Bob and Dense.

Anything can be converted to Dense easily:

```
template<typename T>
Dense to_dense( T&& );
```

Now, there is custom code that lets you convert Dense to Alice or Bob.  Lets use overloads, where we pass a tag parameter to tell us what we want to convert to:

```
template<class T> struct type_tag {};
Alice from_dense( Dense const&, type_tag<Alice> );
Bob from_dense( Dense const&, type_tag<Bob> );
```

these will be maintained by `Alice` and `Bob` respectfully.

Let us suppose that `Alice` and `Bob` belong to some type category -- call it `ConvertUniverse`:

```
template<class T>
constexpr bool InConvertUniverse();
```

where we can say `InConvertUniverse<Alice>()` and get `true`, and `InConvertUniverse<int>()` and get `false` at compile time.  For now, `Dense` is not in said universe.

Lets make a function that can automatically convert anything in said universe to anything else:

```
template<class T> using decay_t = typename std::decay<T>::type;

template<class Src, class Dest>
typename std::enable_if<
  InConvertUniverse< decay_t<Src> >() && InConvertUniverse< Dest >(),
  Dest
>::type
cross_convert( Src&& src, type_tag<Dest> ) {
  return from_dense( to_dense(src), type_tag<Dest>{} );
}
```

Now, `cross_convert( alice, type_tag<Bob>{} )` will return a `Bob`.

We can use this to implement `template` casts to anything `InConvertUniverse<?>()` within `Alice`.  In fact, we can use it to implement such casts within a CRTP parent of `Alice`.

For casting to-from `Dense` you are all good.

The next step is to allow for faster `cross_convert` in special cases.  If you get this far, you'll want to make the global `cross_convert` above have some property that makes it not as preferred as ADL found overloads (such as ending the parameter list with a `...` or `Ts&&...` that you never use).  Then a specific `cross_convert` overload will be preferred I believe.

Now, one annoying misfeature of the above is that ADL doesn't let us stick `from_dense` in the namespace of `Bob` and have it be automatically found, as `type_tag<Dest>{}` exists in an unrelated namespace (in theory).  So replace `type_tag` with:

```
template<class T> using type_tag = T*;
```

and ADL starts kicking in, and we can define `from_dense` in `Alice`'s namespace and have it magically found by `cross_convert`.  It also causes covariant overloading, which is annoying if you have sub-classes of `Alice` hanging around, but that isn't a problem here.